# non static or const array syntax

Tags: c++

what's wrong with this syntax? sorry for the newbie question.

source:

```
Level::Level()
{

    NintyDegreeDirections[4] =  
    { 
        1.0f, 1.4f, 2.4f, 0.1f
    }

...rest of class
```

header:

```
//all necessary includes

class Level
{
private:

    float NintyDegreeDirections[4];

...rest of header
```

how do I have an array as a instance member? I'm converting from C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of C++ (C++11), you can initialize the member array like this:

```
Level::Level()
 : NintyDegreeDirections( { 1.0f, 1.4f, 2.4f, 0.1f } )
{
}
```

C++11 isn't universally supported and if you don't have support for this in your compiler you will have to assign to each member in turn.

E.g.:

```
NintyDegreeDirections[0] = 1.0f;
NintyDegreeDirections[1] = 1.4f;
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
NintyDegreeDirections[0] = 1.0f;
NintyDegreeDirections[1] = 1.4f;
/* ... */
```

Comment: there's no way of initialising all the vaues in one block?

Comment: @SirYakalot Not yet since (troll) C++ isn't as modern as C99.

Comment: @nc3b: Please justify the assertion "C++ is not as modern as C99". (Superficially, C++ would appear to be 12 years more modern than C99.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey I was (half-)trolling, thinking of compound literals.

Comment: can you explain this C++ C99 thing?

Comment: @SirYakalot If you tell me what you want to know in a more specific way.